# INNER JOIN not working form in Sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, inner-join

we have two table `(toRouteCSV7,UpdateFOCQtyTable)`.toRouteCSV7 have two columns. `ItemNumber and FOCQty` and UpdateFOCQtyTable have two columns `ItemID,updatefocvalue`

```
toRouteCSV7 
in 
ItemNumber  FOCQty 
A123           0
A124           0
A125           0
A126           0
```

UpdateFOCQtyTable

```
ItemID    updatefocvalue
A125         1256
A126         14596
```

After Update We need look like this

```
 ItemNumber  FOCQty 
    A123           0
    A124           0
    A125           1256
    A126           14596
```

We tried like this

```
 tx.executeSql('REPLACE INTO toRouteCSV7 (ItemNumber,FOCQty) select dest.ItemNumber,dest.FOCQty,src.ItemID,src.updatefocvalue from UpdateFOCQtyTable src inner join  toRouteCSV7 dest on src.ItemID = dest.ItemNumber');
```

We don't have any luck.We are developing mobile app using phoneGap.Please guide to us

we got error

```
Error Processing SQL:5
Error Processing message SQL:could not prepare statement(1 4 values for 2 columns)
```

Comment: what error u´ve got?

Comment: @eduyayo thanks for reply 
Error Processing SQL:5
Error Processing message SQL:could not prepare statement(1 table toRouteCSV7 has no column named ItemID)

Comment: then I think you´re lacking the column `ItemId` in the table `toRouteCSV7` :P

Comment: @eduyayo ItemId is  column in UpdateFOCQtyTable
toRouteCSV7  have only (ItemNumber  FOCQty) two columns

Comment: yup... but your query says it is in toRoute... `INTO toRouteCSV7 (ItemNumber,FOCQty,ItemID,`

Comment: @eduyayo Please look my update code in question.Please guide to us

Comment: the error now is literally as it sounds, you´re trying to insert/modify four columns in a table of two. See the first tuple has two elements and the select has 4

Comment: @eduyayo sry we are poor in that Please guide to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you want to update a single column, you can simply use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE toRouteCSV7
SET FOCQty = (SELECT updatefocvalue
              FROM UpdateFOCQtyTable
              WHERE ItemID = toRouteCSV7.ItemNumber)
WHERE ItemNumber IN (SELECT ItemID
                     FROM UpdateFOCQtyTable)
```

Comment: thanks for reply.But it's update only last value 
oldcolum   updateFOCQty
5               2
2               1
 .

2               2                
1               1  
Please guide to us

Comment: What do you mean with "only last value", and with these numbers?

Comment: after update FOCQty Value all are same.Like first update FOC value is 20,30 after second update with different number also it's showing 20,30.Now it's showing like 20,30,20,30

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c86c1/1). Make a complete example that shows the problem.